# Component tree is empty for react native app in Android Studio Layout Inspector

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, android-layout

I want to get `resource name` of react native app's component in order to do `firebase robo testing` and I can get through the layout inspector but I'm seeing nothing in the component's tree. Is there something I'm doing wrong or some other alternative to get resource name for android

[image]
You can see there's nothing in the component tree...

Comment: Sitting with the same issue, have you found the solution yet?

Comment: No sorry. Still I did not find any solution.